Minimal polynomial degree formula?
Let $u_i$ be all the distinct zero's of its (irreducible) minimal polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ :
$$ f(x) = x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + a_2 x^{n-2} + ... + a_n $$
where the coefficients $a_j$ are integers.
This implies the zero's are of algebraic degree $n$.
This is well understood.
So I started wondering,
Let $k$ be a given zero of $g(x)$ where
$$ g(x) = x^m + b_1 x^{m-1} + b_2 x^{m-2} + ... + b_m $$
is the (irreducible) minimal polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $m$ for $k$ such that
the coefficients $b_j$ are all algebraic of degree $v$.
Then what is the degree $n$ of the (irreducible) minimal polynomial $f_1(x)$ for $k$ :
$$ f_1(x) = x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + a_2 x^{n-2} + ... + a_n $$
where the coefficients $a_j$ are integers ?
Now a wild guess would give me $n = v m$ but this is probably incorrect.
In fact there probably is no closed form for $n$ in terms of $v$ and $m$ , since it depends on the type of fields and stuff , so I ask ;
what is the upper and lower bound for $n$ in terms of $v$ and $m$ ?
That is the main question.
In case that also has no closed form, what do we know for a fact ?
To show a simple example of its perhaps nontriviality :
try this out: $L=\mathbb Q$, $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{2}$, $\beta=e^{i\pi/4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $L$ is $x^4-2$ (irreducible by Eisenstein for prime $p=2$), while the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ is $x^4+1$ (also easily proven to be irreducible). However, the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $L(\alpha)$ is $(x-\beta)(x-\overline{\beta})=x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1=x^2-\alpha^2x+1$ and is of degree $2$. Thus, $[L(\alpha, \beta):L]=8$ and not $16$, as you might expect.
Additional question ; does this strongly relate to the power law for subgroups ?
or the tower of fields ?
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tower_Law_for_Subgroups
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_fields
